# Get metadata from mp3 file with URL (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, url, metadata, mp3

I'm new in swift and i would like to get data from a mp3 file located on a server, ( i used an URL, exemple : http://myserver.eu/file.mp3 ).

i used some tuto, like http://geekyviney.blogspot.com/2015/02/extracting-data-like-thumbnail-images.html ( it's working with a local file and i'm trying to make it work with a file from an url)
i got a exception : 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

I suppose that pathForResource is only for local file ? thanks for your help

```
var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("http://servername.eu/filename", ofType: "mp3")
        var fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
        var asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(fileUrl) as AVAsset
```

Comment: Make sure you look at any accompany documentation. PathForResource is used for resource files which means local files in the app, not remote ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `pathForResource` is used to access files locally in the application bundle.

To load data from URLs with `http` scheme use this syntax

```
let urlString = "http://servername/filename"
let serverURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
if let asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(serverURL) as? AVAsset {
  // do something with the asset
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version:

```
let urlString = "http://servername/filename"
if let serverURL = URL(string: urlString) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: serverURL)
    // do something with the asset
}
```

Ow and don't forget to add the correct import

```
import AVFoundation
```